# Mutex Initialization -(UNIX)

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, mutex

In the following code.A **mutex** is initialized.what is the significance of **NULL**.

```
pthread_mutex_init(&a->monitor,NULL);
```

I want to know why we pass NULL as the second parameter.

Comment: Could you not just read the man pages for pthread: http://www.rootr.net/man/man/pthread_mutex_init/3

Comment: @Martin York-Thankyou for the info.I will keep that in mind the next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument is a pointer to a `pthread_mutexattr_t` structure, which lets you tweak the behavior of the mutex; NULL means "no special options here, use the default mutex behavior."

Most mutex options are useful only in edge cases (avoiding priority-inversion deadlocks, sharing a mutex between processes rather than threads) and the more useful ones (e.g. recursion control) were only standardized in the 2008 revision of POSIX, which means you can't yet rely on their existence cross-platform.  paxdiablo's answer has a comprehensive list.

Comment: There is a list in the [POSIX `pthreads.h` spec](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pthread.h.html) - see the functions starting with `pthread_mutexattr_`

Comment: They are _not_ poorly standardised, IEEE/OG is on par with ISO re its standards. And most of the time, it's not useful, you're right about that. But there _are_ uses for them, however edgecase they may be.

Comment: I must have been looking at an older version of 1003.1 that only defined the `pshared` property; so I assumed all the other functions in the (glibc) pthread.h on my system were GNU-only extensions.  I'll revise "poorly standardized" to "not very portable" -- anything only in 1003.1-2008 is too new to rely on cross-platform, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

`NULL`, as a mutex attribute, gives you an implementation defined default attribute. If you want to know what you can do with attributes, check out the [following reference](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pthread.h.html#tag_13_35) and follow the `pthread_mutexattr_*` links in the `SEE ALSO` section.

This is for issue 7 of the standard, 1003.1-2008. The starting point for that is [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Clicking on `Headers` in the bottom left will allow you to navigate to the specific functionality (including `pthreads.h`).

The attributes allow you to set or get:

- the [type](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_gettype.html#) (deadlocking, deadlock-detecting, recursive, etc).
- the [robustness](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getrobust.html#) (what happens when you acquire a mutex and the original owner died while possessing it).
- the [process-shared attribute](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html#) (for sharing a mutex across process boundaries).
- the [protocol](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol.html#) (how a thread behaves in terms of priority when a higher-priority thread wants the mutex).
- the [priority ceiling](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getprioceiling.html#) (the priority at which the critical section will run, a way of preventing priority inversion).

And, of course, there's the [init and destroy calls](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_destroy.html#) as well, not directly related to a specific attribute but used to create them.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of pthread_mutex_init takes the pthread_mutexattr_t as argument.
You can use the second argument to specify the attributes to the mutex and if its NULL default mutex attributes are used.